# Какой онлайн-кошелек выбрать для работы с Webmoney,visa,яндекс деньги и киви?

Tags: платежи

Появилась задача привязать к сайту 4 платежные системы,а именно webmoney,qiwi,яндекс деньги и visa.Т.к заказчик кошельки ни какие не предоставил,выбрать его нужно мне.Какой агрегатор выбрать,чтобы я смог его привязать ко всем выше перечисленным системам.

Answer (score 1):

Я рекомендую выбрать одну из двух систем:

- [SwiftPay](https://swiftpay.ru). Способ оплаты достаточно ограничен, но комиссия низкая.
- [Free-Kassa](https://www.free-kassa.ru). Куда шире выбор способа оплаты, но выше комиссия.